# Sitecore Custom Databases for user generated content

Tags: sql-database

I need to store a set of information (for example, poll results, article comments, etc,).

I would like to use the Sitecore pattern to manage information (templates, items and content tree) in order to not deploy custom logic for custom SQL database.

Of course, I don't want to use the master (CM) database since items are not available in the web (CD) database (unless I publish them).
On the other site I cannot create items in web (CD) database since they are lost on publishing.

Is there a way to add a customer database to the content tree structure avoiding the publication.

Thanks in advance, 
Tex

Answer (score 6):

### Yes

You can add as many databases as you like.

I have an admittedly very old tutorial that takes you through the steps. Having just skimmed through it, I would say it's probably still perfectly valid - as Sitecore's Data Provider model hasn't changed significantly in a decade.

- [Working with multiple content databases in Sitecore 6](http://intothecore.cassidy.dk/2009/05/working-with-multiple-content-databases.html)

But if you want to go on your own, the steps to add an additional database to your solution is roughly this:

- Clone one of your existing SQL databases. E.g. "master" or "web".
- Add a new `<database>` section to your configs. Patch it in. Give it a unique id, i.e. change "master" to "ugc" or something similar.
- Add a matching connection string for your cloned database in ConnectionStrings.config

And that's more or less it. As long as you can access this database, you can access the content in it - no publishing required or even wanted.

If you really wanted this information to come into your "master" content tree, you could set up a proxy for it. I'm not sure I would recommend you do however.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you suggestions, I'll check and let you know!!

Comment: @Mark-Cassidy is this supported on Sitecore 9.1.1 PaaS? We have a small custom database we need to run which holds customer details. Thanks

Comment: Absolutely. This is supported in any version and topology since version 5.